# Read specific string value from text file

Tags: excel, vba

Hi Can anyone please help as soon as possible to read a specific value from a text file,

here is my input file,

config.txt

```
<DatabaseConnectionString>
"Provider=SQL;Password=pa;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=s;Initial Catalog=L;Data Source=C.com"
</DatabaseConnectionString>
```

I need to get only the text inside the connection string tag in VBA

Comment: Simply listing your requirements and asking for help is not a good way to ask a question on this site. Please see [Why is "Can someone Help me" not an "actual" question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question). Show us how _you_ tried to solve the problem yourself, then show us _exactly_ what the result was, and tell us why you feel it didn't work.

Comment: I have tried to read the file like an xml ,  but am getting the error Object not refferred error 424. Cant we read the file like xml even if we doesnt added any attributes.? i tried like docxml.selectsinglenode(" /DatabaseConnectionString/text() ")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the start, now you need to go into your files or something else to fill your initial string, `DbC` here in the code :

```
Sub Minu_Manjaly()

Dim DbC As String

DbC = CStr("<DatabaseConnectionString>" & Chr(34) & _
        "Provider=SQL;Password=pa;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=s;Initial Catalog=L;Data Source=C.com" & _
        Chr(34) & "</DatabaseConnectionString>")

MsgBox GetDB_Connect(DbC)

End Sub
```

And here is the function :

```
Public Function GetDB_Connect(ByVal DB_Connect_Str As String) As String
    Dim CsT As String, _
        StartS As Long

    StartS = InStr(1, DB_Connect_Str, "<DatabaseConnectionString>")

    CsT = Mid(DB_Connect_Str, StartS + Len("<DatabaseConnectionString>"), _
            InStr(StartS, DB_Connect_Str, "</DatabaseConnectionString>") - StartS - Len("</DatabaseConnectionString>") + 1)

    GetDB_Connect = CsT
End Function
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for the reply.. i have tried something similiar to that and it worked fine..  Here is the code i used                                                                                                 str = ReadFromFile("C:\\Config.txt")
        openPos = InStr(str, "<DatabaseConnectionString>")
        closePos = InStr(str, "</DatabaseConnectionString>")
        connstring = Mid(str, openPos + 27, closePos - openPos - 27)
        connstring = Replace(connstring, """", "")

Comment: Indeed! So is your problem solved? If yes, plz validate answer to set the subject as solved! ;)